# Have I resolved my database relationships correctly?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place for this question.  I volunteer for a charity group that has to store sensitive data, as we are a new type of format, there are no systems that fit within our needs or our budget.  Someone else started building the database, I wasn't sure he was resolving the relationships correctly, so I presented him with an alternate ER model and now we haven't heard back from him, so I am left to build it by myself.
As we have to store sensitive data, I'm reluctant to put my database design on here in it's entirety, so if there is a way I can privately discuss this with someone, that would be my preference, as I would love to get someone else to check it in full to make sure it's ALL good... but for now, can someone confirm if I have resolved the relationships correctly, or if the original design was better?

The database description is:  There are different types of members -

```
Client, Staff, Professional (Offsite), Supplier, Family, General.  There are different types of Staff members: Managers, Volunteer, Professional (Onsite), Admin, Committee, Lecturer. A member can be one or many types eg: Client/Volunteer/Family, Supplier/Volunteer, Manager/Lecturer/Volunteer/Committee/Family.
```

The original guy resolved this by creating a separate table for each user, each table storing a name and address eg:

```
Client - ClientName, ClientAddress
Professional - ProfessionalName, ProfessionalAddress
Employee - EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress
Family - FamilyName, FamilyAddress
```

My only problem with this is that I would ideally like one person to have one MemberID with their name and address, but with the original design each person would have a different ID for each type of person that they were, all storing name, address, phone number, email etc.

I thought that creating a Member table and having a Member Type table with a joining Member Type List table would be a better design.  This is how I have resolved the issue:

[Member Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6oP8.jpg)

Have I done this correctly or should I continue with the original design?

Thanks

Update:

[Staff Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxmEq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to store all member related data within one table.
Also for programming, I cannot imagine any use case that would support having different tables for each member type.

That being said, I advise you to look up the concept of "user roles", since this seems very similar.

You have different users (members) and they can have different roles (member type). Based on your roles you might want to show different data / allow different actions / send specific mails (or whatever else you can imagine).

So generally your approach looks good. The only thing I think about is that right now you don't have stored who is a "Staff" member for example. If you just have one list with different names you don't store the structure.
Depending on your use cases you can e.g. make another column in `MemberType` table "isStaff". Or, if you need to be more flexible and there are likely more different member types in the future, you can make another table (e.g.)  `MemberTypeParent` and set a foreign key on your MemberType table to that table to make the connection.

It all depends on what you want to do with the data in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! To resolve the MemberType is Staff issue I created a StaffTable and joined it to the MemberType table with a MemberTypeStaffTable.  I got confused here again, as I created a StaffTypeTable to store the different types of Staff, and then joined it to the StaffTable with a StaffTypeListTable to list the different types of staff a person may be (1 person can be a Committee Member & Volunteer). As I already have the diff types of members stored in the MemberTypeList table I wasn't sure if I was creating lists on top of lists?  I will add the model for Staff to my q.